# Pre-population of checkbox smartcapture in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, smart-capture

I have multiple radio and checkboxes that I need to pre-populate in a form but every combo I have tried doesn't work.

Can any tell me what I am doing wrong please as I've spent hours on this now with no joy.

1. In email the link goes back to form and does populate text fields with
   Make changes to form
2. In body
   SET @Q_HAD_DETOX = Lookup("FACIAL_APPOINTMENT_FORM","Q_HAD_DETOX","EMAIL", @EMAIL)
3. In form, I have tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Q_HAD_DETOX" id="Q_HAD_DETOX" 
data-field-type="Boolean" 
%%[IF @Q_HAD_DETOX == True THEN]%% 
value="TRUE" checked="TRUE" %%[Else]%% 
%%[ENDIF]%%> 
Completed a detox dietary regimen in the past two months?</label></div>
```

```
<div class="sc-formfield-input"><label>
<input type="checkbox" name="Q_HAD_DETOX" id="Q_HAD_DETOX" 
data-field-type="Boolean" 
%%[IF @Q_HAD_DETOX == True THEN]%% value="Y" type="checkbox" checked/ %%[Else]%% 
%%[ENDIF]%%>
```

```
<div class="sc-formfield-input"><label>
<input type="checkbox" name="Q_HAD_DETOX" id="Q_HAD_DETOX" 
data-field-type="Boolean"  
%%[IF @Q_HAD_DETOX == "TRUE" THEN]%%checked%%[ENDIF]%%>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Q_HAD_DETOX" id="Q_HAD_DETOX" 
data-field-type="Boolean" value="@Q_HAD_DETOX">
```

There are more versions but you can see the general format I have been trying by looking at other posts on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with quite minimal code:

```ampscript
%%[
SET @whatever = true
]%%
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose your checkbox:</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="whatever" name="whatever" %%=IIF(@whatever,'checked','')=%% />
    <label for="whatever">Whatever</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

As you can see, IIF (Inline IF) is quite efficient way of placing conditional text/html in your page.

And looking at your code, I suspect the issue is also related to how you are handling the boolean variable in your code. Please ensure the `@Q_HAD_DETOX` indeed is of boolean type (by checking the field of the *FACIAL_APPOINTMENT_FORM* data extension in which you are looking it up).

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I tried  <input type="checkbox" id="Q_HAD_DETOX" name="Q_HAD_DETOX" %%=IIF(@whatever,'checked','')=%% /> and  <input type="checkbox" id="Q_HAD_DETOX" name="Q_HAD_DETOX" value=%%=IIF(@whatever,'checked','')=%% />

Comment: @NickyB - please check the value of _@whatever_, as this is probably not of boolean type. The code I provided is working, so please also include %%[
SET _@whatever = true_
]%% when validating whether you are able to set the checkbox dynamically using ampscript.

Comment: Thank you @lukas. This worked perfectly

Comment: You're welcome, @NickyB - remember to mark my answer as accepted